# OData orderBy by nested collection items

Tags: odata

```
public class ViewModel {
    public string ModelId{ get; set; }
    public List<City > Cities{ get; set; } = new();
}

public class City {
    public string CityId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Created{ get; set; }
}
```

Using OData query: how can I do sorting(orderBy) of List by Created where CityId={someValue}

I tried to find how we can get an element from a nested list, but I didn't find anything about it, in general, it is possible to somehow extract an element from an list in OData and then sort by it?